# Magento2 get variants of configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

I'm new to Magento2 and finding it difficult to get information.
I'm trying to read simple (variants) products of a configurable product on the view page.

I created my custom block that extends AbstractProduct.

Then I was able to get upsell product ids like this:

```
$product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
$upSellProductIds = $product->getUpSellProductIds();
```

Now, how to get variants(simple products).

In Magento 1.x, I used **getUsedProductCollection()**

Please help

Comment: can you please show your working example I need the same but I can't get workin

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with `$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product)`.

Comment: should check condition if product is configurable then getUsedProducts() medthod work otherwise throw error.

Answer (score 3):

You can get child product of current configurable product by this simple code:

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

    echo $product->getId(); //Main configurable product ID
    echo $product->getName(); //Main Configurable Name

    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {
        echo $child->getId()."</br>"; //Child Product Id  
        echo $child->getName()."</br>"; //Child Product Name
    }
```